# Is this PL/SQL code ACID compliant?

Tags: oracle, plsql, acid

Is it OK to issue asynchronous commits on TEMPORARY tables? Does it make my transactions less durable?

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_table_tmp (id number) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
CREATE TABLE my_table (id number);

BEGIN
  INSERT --+ append
  INTO my_table_tmp (id)
  SELECT rownum 
  FROM all_objects;

  COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT; -- continue working without waiting on LGWR

  INSERT INTO my_table (id)
  SELECT id 
  FROM my_table_tmp;

  COMMIT; -- actually preserve transaction
END;
/
```

Edit:

Yes, I understand that it is not strictly ACID because it bypasses the D part for a split second. The question is - is it "as good as" ACID because there is no possible scenario where it is different from the version where only real COMMITs are used? Or am I mistaken and there can be a difference?

Comment: You are aware that you can do this with just a single statement?

Comment: I am aware. This is just the simplest example of what I intend to do.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: no. The D in ACID stands for Durability, which means that a commit 100% guarantees that the transaction is preserved even if the database should crash immediately after. An asynchronous commit provides a window of opportunity for this aspect of ACID to be violated.

More information on the advantages/disadvantages of using asynchronous commit is here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/93

Comment: Yes, I read that article before asking. What would be the difference between COMMIT and COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT if the database crashes while executing the second insert? Should I care that I can not restore data in the temporary table?

Comment: The difference is that with a regular commit, your first insert would be preserved should the database fail during the second insert. With an asynchronous commit, the first insert might not be preserved if the database failed during the redo log write operation. Whether or not this is important to you or not is a case-by-case basis, and you may choose to trade-off speed for durability.

Comment: I understand that the first insert can be lost. The question is - does that matter in this particular example code? Does it matter if I lost redo if there were only non-permanent changes in it anyway? Notice the TEMPORARY keyword on first table.

Comment: The question of whether it matters or not is purely down to what is important for your implementation. If you are not concerned that the temporary table data might be lost during a failure then asynchronous commit is a perfectly reasonable option.